# Get the value of the Future<Map<String,String>> in FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Future method like below:

```
Future<Map<String,String>> readFavorites() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    names = prefs.getKeys();
    for (var key in names) {
      debugPrint("key is " + key);
      debugPrint("value is " + prefs.get(key));
      pairs.putIfAbsent(key, () => prefs.get(key));
    }
    return pairs;
  }
```

I want to get the snapshot length plus the map's values in the futurebuilder below:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: readFavorites(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String,String>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              //replace this with a loading icon
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemExtent: 90,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length, <== How to get the map length? 
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SingleDish(
                    dish_name: snapshot.data[index],
                    dish_picture: snapshot.data[index]., <== How to get the value from the map? 
                  );
                });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried the following but I got a null exception: snapshot.data[snapshot.data[index]]. Will appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

What is interesting is that when I printed the key I got the following:

**lib_cached_image_data_last_clean**

```
  Future<Map<String, String>> readFavorites() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    names = prefs.getKeys();
    //This  returned  the correct value because I hardcoded the key
    print("hardcoded key is " + prefs.getString("Cutlet"));
    for (var key in names) {
      //This fellow here returned lib_cached_image_data_last_clean
      print("key is" + key);
       pairs.putIfAbsent(key, () => prefs.get(key));
     // print("key is "  + pairs.length.toString());
    }
    return pairs;
  }
```

So, I know for a fact that readFavorites() returns values. But am not sure why the key is not what I added in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: `snapshot.data` is a `Map<String,String>` right? so use [Map](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html) api to get your data

Comment: But I want to use the snapshot. How can I access it via snapshot?

Comment: `Map<String,String> favorites = snapshot.data;`

Comment: How do I use the map to iterate through the builder and get the key value pair?

Comment: i gave you a link in my first comment, didnt i?

Comment: The link doesn't answer question. I specifically want to access the map value inside the itembuilder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this code it is auto explained and you can adapt this code to your needs.

```
Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: readFavorites(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String,String>> snapshot) {
          switch( snapshot.connectionState){
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Text("there is no connection");

            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center( child: new CircularProgressIndicator());

            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.data != null){
                Map<String,String> myMap = Map.from( snapshot.data ); // transform your snapshot data in map
                var keysList = myMap.keys.toList(); // getting all keys of your map into a list

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemExtent: 90,
                    itemCount: myMap.length, // getting map length you can use keyList.length too
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return SingleDish(
                        dish_name: keysList[index], // key
                        dish_picture:  myMap[ keysList[index] ], // getting your map values from current key
                      );
                    }
                );
              }
              // here your snapshot data is null so SharedPreferences has no data...
              return Text("No data was loaded from SharedPreferences");
          }//end switch

        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The code worked fine. However, when I restarted my app and added an item to favorites and then accessed the favorites list, I got null exception at this line: 
Map.from( snapshot.data ); although sharedpreferences contains data.

Comment: I am getting the following exception on that line: The method 'forEach' was called on null.

Comment: I change the source code it is more verbose now i don't know if will solve the problem but this approach will help you figure out. "Null pointer exception" in line Map.from( snapshot.data ); means that snapshot has no data in dart we can use nullable operators "? " and "??" to solve this, but i have used if() blocks to avoid this exceptions. If 'forEach' was called on null was in your readFavorites method then the line prefs.getKeys(); is returning null to your names variable what means that SharedPreferences has no keys and the problem can be when you write data into this.

Comment: With the current version of flutter, this solution contain an error in line
"Map<String, String> myMap = Map.from(snapshot.data);"

error message "The argument type 'Map<String, String>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'."

Comment: will work with
Map<String,String> myMap = snapshot.data as Map<String, String>;